# Trabalhando com delay's em Android. Melhor abordagem?

Tags: java, android, thread

**Duvida**

Recentemente necessitei a utilização de uma `delay` em minha aplicação para executar determinado código, após algum tempo.

Pesquisando "pelas internet's", encontrei algumas "Gambi's", e encontrei um abordagem um tanto quando nova para mim, que testei e achei muito eficiente (até agora), que é [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3039718/2290538) e é basicamente a seguinte:

```java
Handler handler = new Handler();
long delay = 1000; // tempo de delay em millisegundos
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // código a ser executado após o tempo de delay
    }
}, delay);
```

**Pergunta**

Como não sei como esse código funciona (internamente), não consigo saber se isso se comporta bem com Android, ou se pode me trazer problemas no futuro. Já que implementações que envolvem manipulação de Threads devem ter sempre uma atenção especial.

- **Então gostaria de saber como ele funcionar (internamente) e se é eficiente utiliza-lo em Android?**
- **Ou ainda se há alguma abordagem melhor para está situação?**

Estou aberto a mudar meu código para evitar problemas futuros.

> Obs: A questão aqui não é criar um `Timer`, que execute a cada intervalo de tempo, e sim um código que espere um determinado tempo para depois ser executado, não bloqueando a Thread principal da aplicação.

Comment: O certo é usar o handler mesmo. Não use o sleep em aplicações Android.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Já tive a mesma dúvida que você teve, logo vou arriscar uma resposta.

Acredito que seja melhor começar por um conceito muito importante no Android, que é o `Looper`.

## Looper

O `Looper` é uma classe que é usada para tratamento de mensagens usando fila. Isso é, quando uma `Thread` quer receber mensagens de diversas threads e executar processamento **thread-safe**, é um `Looper` que deve ser usado.

O `Looper`, juntamente com o `Handler` basicamente transforma a `Thread` **corrente** (acredito que isso é feito usando o método `Thread.currentThread` espero) em um *pipeline*, onde são adicionadas mensagens a esse *pipeline*, processadas pela `Thread`e liberadas.<sup>1</sup>

Esse trecho de código pode ajudar:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Prepara o looper na thread corrente     
            // a thread corrente vai ser detectada implicitamente
            Looper.prepare();

            // Agora, vamos automaticamente ligar o Handler
            // ao Looper que foi ligado a thread corrente
            // Você não precisar especificar o Looper explicitamente, ele saberá
            handler = new Handler();

            // Depois dessa linha, a Thread ira iniciar de fato
            // Rodando o loop de mensagens (Looper) e nao ira
            // terminar o loop ate que um problema ocorra ou 
            // voce chame o metodo quit() do Looper
            Looper.loop();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "halted due to an error", t);
        } 
    }
}
```

Logo para tratar as mensagens enviadas para essa `Thread`, você pode enviar um `Runnable`:

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {       
        // Isso sera feito no pipeline da Thread ligada a esse Handler
    }
});
```

Ou postar uma mensagem, usando o `obtainMessage` e usando o método `sendMessage`. Algo como:

```
Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(what);
// Popular mensagem com dados
handler.sendMessage(msg);
// ou
msg.setTarget(handler);
msg.sendToTarget();
```

É claro que terá que implementar um `Handler` fazendo sobrecarga do método `handleMessage` para ter acesso as mensagens enviadas.

Bom, essa parte espero que tenha sido entendida, agora irei para a parte relativa a resposta.

## UI Thread ou Main Thread

Acredito que tenha ouvido falar bastante, é nessa `Thread` que o Android realiza todas as operações em relação a interface gráfica e outras relacionadas a recursos do aplicativo. Seja modificando/inflando o layout, gerenciando `Activities` (O que inclui tratamento de eventos de toque), `Fragments`, `Services`, `ContentProviders` e `BroadcastReceivers`<sup>2</sup>. Por isso que acesso a esses componentes devem ser feitos na `Main Thread`, pois todo esse processamento não é `Thread-Safe`, tendo um custo muito grande e riscos de ser (imagina se acontece um deadlock ?!?).

Acho que esse `StackTrace` que gerei pode ajudar a visualizar isso:

> java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
>               at br.com.planning.poker.app.activity.CustomDeckActivity.onCreate(CustomDeckActivity.java:82)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Dá pra ver que para iniciar/criar minha `Activity` (que gerou essa exceção), ele precisou enviar uma mensagem para o `Looper` da `Main Thread` (que é iniciada pelo `Zygote`), para que seja processado.

Chegando ao cerne da sua dúvida, esse código não será executado fora da `Main Thread`*, justamente porque você está enviando uma mensagem para a `Main Thread`, para que ELA processe, o que irá travar outros processamentos (tornando seu aplicativo não responsivo a toque, gerando **ANR**).

*Acredito que o contexto dele seja a `Main Thread`.

Podem haver outras formas de fazer mas eu sempre faço dessa maneira:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new AsynctTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // Processamento fora da Main Thread
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                // Processamento na Main Thread (podendo alterar a UI)
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}, delay);
```

Com relação a processamentos fora da `Main Thread`, existem também os [`Loaders`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) que facilitam muito a forma de acesso a banco local e a notificação da disponibilidade dos dados. Um tutorial que usei para aprender foi:  http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html. Ele é mais simples e mais que o oficial, mas não substitui é claro.

## Thread Sleep vs Handler

Além da abordagem usando `Handler` que é sem dúvidas mais vantajoso, não há perda de performance usando `Handler` na `Main Thread` porque o `Looper` já foi inicializado anteriormente. O [construtor da classe `Handler`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/os/Handler.java#Handler.%3Cinit%3E%28android.os.Handler.Callback%2Cboolean%29) busca uma instância do `Looper` no `ThreadLocal`, logo não há criação da filas e nada extra porque esse `Looper` é criado pelo `Zygote`.

Na abordagem de `AsyncTask` há um custo relativamente alto de criação de uma `Thread` só para usar `Thread.sleep` e depois executar um processamento.

Se o processamento for feito em `background` na solução por `Handler` também há o custo de se criar uma `AsyncTask`, porém entra em questão a ordem de execução das `Threads` no Android.

- Antes do Android 1.6, todo o escalonamento de `Threads` era serial. De fato o `Thread.sleep` causa problemas nesse cenário por "travar" o escalonamento.<sup>3</sup>
- Entre o Android 1.6 e o 2.3, o escalonamento se tornou paralelo. Logo o `Thread.sleep` não causaria problemas.<sup>3</sup>
- No android 3.0 o escalonamento padrão voltou a ser serial (devido a problemas no paralelismo), mas se introduziu uma forma de se escalonar em paralelo usando `Executors`, sendo uma forma de superar o problema do serial.<sup>3</sup>

## Mudança de configuração

Existe um problema recorrente no uso de `AsyncTask` e o ciclo de vida da `Activity`/`Fragment`. O problema ocorre quando se inicia uma `AsyncTask` e enquanto seu processamento não termina acontece a destruição ou parada da `Activity`. Logo quando for atualizar a UI ao final, não é a mesma `Activity` e consequentemente pode ocorrer leak de memória. Esse post ajuda a visualizar o problema e uma solução: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Para isso é recomendado o uso de `Loaders`, que são gerenciados automaticamente em virtude do ciclo de vida da `Activity`.

Espero que tenha ficado claro, apesar de eu não saber o quanto você sabia desses detalhes, tentei fazer o mais abrangente para que outras pessoas com essa mesma dúvida possa aproveitar.

Qualquer detalhe é só falar que eu complemento minha resposta.

Referências:

1. http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652560/what-is-the-android-uithread-ui-thread
3. http://www.jayway.com/2012/11/28/is-androids-asynctask-executing-tasks-serially-or-concurrently/

Comment: Faltou acrescentar uns detalhes sobre `Thread` que irei fazer em breve.

Comment: Entendi sua colocação (eu acho), no caso então o `postDelayed` do `Handler`, é eficiente com Android, o que ele faz é enviar um `Runnable` para ser executado posteriormente, e no caso da maneira que ele fiz ele executaria o código do `Runnable` na Thread principal, e no caso você deu a sugestão de se eu quiser executar em uma outra Thread, para não bloquear a Thread principal do Android, se for alguma tarefa demorada (pesada), eu deveria criar um `AsynctTask` no `Runnable`. Certo?

Comment: Exatamente, em breve (quando eu chegar a um computador) irei comentar mais algumas coisa pra deixar a resposta mais completa.

Comment: Muito, boa sua explicação, em relação a Thread, principalmente o tópico **Thread Sleep vs Handler**, que demonstra as vantagens e o que acontece em cada abordagem.

Answer (score 2):

Aconselho vc utilizar uma AsyncTask.

Seria interessante fazer algo assim:

```
new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
               // aqui vc pode bloquear a execução por um tempo
               try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                   } 
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
               // aqui vc pode bloquear a execução da thread
                     try {
                         Thread.sleep(5000);
                     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                     } 
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
                // mais código aqui
            }
        }.execute();
```

Isso vc poderia executar uma operação depois de um intervalo de tempo e não bloqueará a Thread principal.

Espero ter ajudado!!!

Comment: Você poderia colocar esse código que vc postou dentro da `AsyncTask` que funcionará, porém acho desnecessário manipular um `Handle` sendo que vc pode fazer `Thread.sleep(5000);`

Comment: Não é problemático utilizar `Thread.sleep(5000);` em Android? Mesmo que seja em background, já li em algum lugar(que não lembro) que `Thread.sleep` em Android é um erro. Por exemplo, se meu `AsyncTask` utilizar `SERIAL_EXECUTOR`, se houverem outras threads elas, não serão executadas até que esse seja finalizada. Não me parece uma boa ideia. Certo?

Comment: Fernando: nunca li nada a respeito. Achei que não faz mal usar, até pq eu vi isso sendo implementado em uma app de exemplo da google (mais especificamente, a app de exemplo do GCM, na classe GcmIntentService.java). Então se houver controversas, eu gostaria de saber para poder fazer melhores implementações! Obrigado!!

Comment: No [resposta do Wakim](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22656/trabalhando-com-delays-em-android-melhor-abordagem/22676#22676) o tópico **Thread Sleep vs Handler**, ilustra esse cenário.

Comment: Entendi, eu nao tenho reputação para comentar lá. **Thread Sleep** dá certo pra mim pq eu to programando na API 18, e como foi postado lá, não há problemas nessa abordagem nos Androids mais atuais. Obrigado a todos por esclarecerem isso!

Answer (score 2):

Verificando algumas implementações nativas do Android, para entender o funcionamento e poder criar algumas customizações em minha implementação. Me deparei com uma abordagem nativa e anexada ao Objecto View do Android, que disponibiliza uma implementação de `postDelayed`, para serem utilizadas no Objecto View do Android, dando a sensação que essa parece ser mesmo a melhor abordagem para a utilização de delays em Android, segue o código da [View nativa do Android retirada do código fonte do Android](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#13002):

```java
public boolean postDelayed(Runnable action, long delayMillis) {
    final AttachInfo attachInfo = mAttachInfo;
    if (attachInfo != null) {
        return attachInfo.mHandler.postDelayed(action, delayMillis);
    }
    // Assume that post will succeed later
    ViewRootImpl.getRunQueue().postDelayed(action, delayMillis);
    return true;
}
```

Pelo que pode-se perceber ele já faz alguns tratamentos, a cerca de Thread-safe, para evitar problemas. Um pouco mais abrangente que a implementação sugerida na pergunta utilizando diretamente o Objecto Handler:

```java
Handler handler = new Handler();
long delay = 1000; // tempo de delay em millisegundos
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // código a ser executado após o tempo de delay
    }
}, delay);
```

Então uma melhor maneira de implementar esse código seria utilizando o método `postDelayed` do Objecto View:

```java
long delay = 1000; // tempo de delay em millisegundos
instanciaDaView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // código a ser executado após o tempo de delay
    }
}, delay);
```

Essa abordagem é utilizada nas classes nativas do Android, como por exemplo a [AbsListView que eu estava estudando](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java)

> Para minha surpresa essa abordagem já está disponível desde a `API level 1` do Android, como demostrado [aqui na documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)).